# How to make a scrollable view in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll

i am looking to create an "options" page for my application and because they are many , the screen of the phone is not enough to show.

So i need the user to be able to scroll down the view to see more options till the last. I know i should use the scrollview , but i dont know how.

All the tutorials i ve found are about scrolling all over the screen , zooming , scrolling from left to right , but nothing on how u can create a simple page scrolling up and down.

How exactly do i do that? Do i make many .nib files and somehow i connect them? Do i make a big .nib file?

Can someone guide me to a tutorial on that?

Comment: It might be as easy as subclassing `UIScrollView` rather than `UIView`?

Comment: I am sorry , i m new to iOS , i almost have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Use `UITableview` in grouped mode for showing options. That could be better

Comment: In your view's header file you will see `@interface YourView : UIView` which means that `YourView` is a a subclass of `UIView`.  Change `UIView` to `UIScrollView` and see what happens.  I have no experience of this personally and I'm sure there is more to it, but I think that is going in the right direction.

Comment: Anil , if i do that the whole screen will be a table view? Cause i want to have a map there too.

Comment: You could put the map in one of the table view section headers?

Comment: No idea if possible and how much customization would need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ContentSize` property of `UIScrollView` to scroll what ever area you want. i.e.

take `UIScrollView` add it on `UIView` with exist height of iPhone. i.e. max 460.0
So `ScrollView` frame will be max (0,0,320.0,460.0).

Now after adidng `ScrollView` to `View` set `ContentSize` property to upto  scrollable area.

```
[self.mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.mainScrollView.frame.size.width, 1000.0)];
```

Comment: I dont doubt what you are saying , but i cant understand what i should do. Can you post a simple working example , or a tutorial?

Comment: Clearly provided the line of code which make full fill your req. After adding ScrollView Just write what i have provide line. with your required height of full view which you want to see.

Comment: Where do i put this line of code? In which method? viewdidload?

Comment: Hey after adding your ScrollView add this line where ever your create it. If it is from NIb take IBOutlet of it, and write in ViewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIScrollView *mainScroll = [[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]autorelease];//scrollview width and height

mainScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;   
mainScroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

mainScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height);//width and height depends your scroll area

..........

//add  subviews to your scrollview.....
[mainScroll addSubview:view1]

............

[mainScroll addSubview:view2]

..............

[mainScroll addSubview:view3]

[self.view addSubview:mainScroll];
```

Note :: contentSize property determines your scroll 
        area.Scrolling 
enabled only if your scrollview content larger than scrollview height..

Comment: Thank you works like a charm :) . Now adding subviews means that i need to create all my elements by code? for example if i want to put a button or a text , i have to code it or can i use the builder? And if i can use the builder how can i place something somewhere that would be in the scrolling area? I mean in a place where you dont see it in the first screen but you have to scroll to it.

Comment: @d0nparalias , by my answer add subviews to by code.Otherwise you first add scrollview to your builder then add subviews to your scrollview..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Table View with static Cells, that will scroll automatically if it needs to, much easier. Also with a Table View you can choose to scroll up, down, left, right, set bouncing etc from the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Make only 1 nib file.
give height of scroll view large as you want.
then place your buttons , textfeild on scroll view

Comment: crashes. Its not that simple. i am sure u need to put some code on the controller too.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways :**

- make settings bundel for your app check this [Press Me](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html)
- to make UITableView with custom cells >> it is easy if you use
  Interface Builder [Press Me](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)